# The type or namespace name 'AForge' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, aforge

i am working on a website in which i used Aforge.Math.dll file.
it is working perfectly on localhost but when i upload it on server. It Gives me Following Error:-

```
                      The type or namespace name 'AForge' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can Anybody tell me what is the problem???

Thanks in advance....

Comment: That means `Aforge.Math.dll` could not be found on server, but it is present on your localhost. What's the location of the dll on your localhost?

Comment: in Bin Folder in my Website

Comment: sounds like appropriate location. Then I'd recommend you to [Enable Fusion Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) and read the logs. Or post them here.

Comment: I Solved it. Actually it was directory problem as you suggested.Thanks to you